# Use telnet to check that VNC port is open

Tags: remote-desktop, mac, vnc, telnet

I am supposed to connect to a Mac VNC/ARD server. Let's say that the Mac VNC server has the **hypothetical IP address** `8.8.8.8`.

I want to check if the Mac VNC server even listens to the default VNC port `5900`.

So I ran:

```
telnet 8.8.8.8 5900
```

This times out. I arrive at the conclusion that the Mac VNC server doesn't use the default port (or some other substantial connection problem is the case). It is not a wrong password or wrong color setting, etc.

Is the above conclusion correct?

Comment: If it helps the built in Mac VNC server (known as screen sharing or ARD) does default to port 5900. To change it is not straight forward as it requires editing a file using sudo as described here https://superuser.com/questions/148095/how-to-change-the-default-screen-sharing-vnc-port-number-on-mac-os-x . I would check that screen sharing is turned on in System Preferences - Sharing, if it is check it is listening using the following command in the Terminal app: netstat -an -f inet -p tcp | grep LISTEN . If you don't see 5900 in the output chances are it isn't listening for connections.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is correct...

If it were open you would get a blank screen, and if it were closed, it would say connection refused. Timing out is the same as closed in most cases.